# Optional parameter for Laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I want to make a route for these two URLs:

```
http://localhost/myweb/public/compare
http://localhost/myweb/public/compare/fb
```

Here is the rout I've written:

```
Route::get('compare/{fb?}', 'compareController@index');
```

It doesn't work as expected. Because it also works for this:

```
http://localhost/myweb/public/compare/anythingElse
```

While I want to devote it only for those two URLs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

All I need to do is using [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) method. Something like this:

```
Route::get('compare/{fb?}', 'compareController@index')->where('fb', 'fb');
```

`->where('fb', 'fb')` restricts that optional parameter to only the word of `fb` literally.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)